# Reading multiple data from string, separated by characters using sstream

Tags: c++, ifstream, sstream

I have `.txt` file with text like this inside (this is just a fragment):

```
...
[332, 605]-[332, 592], srednica: 13
[324, 593]-[332, 605], srednica: 14.4222
[323, 594]-[332, 605], srednica: 14.2127
[323, 594]-[331, 606], srednica: 14.4222
[324, 593]-[324, 607], srednica: 14
[323, 594]-[323, 607], srednica: 13
[319, 596]-[319, 607], srednica: 11
[320, 595]-[320, 607], srednica: 12
...
```

What i need to to is get a first 4 numbers from each line and store them into integers.

I have tried smth like this:

```
ifstream file("punkty_srednice.txt");
string line;
int ax, ay, bx, by;
while(getline(file, line)) {
    stringstream s(line);
    string tmp;
    s >> tmp >> ax >> tmp >> ay >> tmp >>  bx >> tmp >> by >> tmp;
    cout << ax  << " " << ay <<  " " << bx << " " << by << endl;
}
```

Output (just a part of it):

```
...
506 506 -858993460 -858993460
503 503 -858993460 -858993460
495 503 -858993460 -858993460
497 503 -858993460 -858993460
500 497 -858993460 -858993460
492 503 -858993460 -858993460
...
```

As u an see there are some strange numbers like `-858993460`

I did other try by deleting `tmp` and going straight like this:

```
s >> ax >> ay >>  bx >> by;
```

but then output contains only trash numbers like `-858993460`

How i can deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) with the `','` as separator to get the first parts, with the numbers. Then replace all non-digit characters with space (see e.g. [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform)). Then put the resulting string in an [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) and read four numbers from it.

---

Some tips on what's wrong with your code, it mostly boils down to that when used with strings, the input operator `>>` reads *space delimited* strings.

So for the line

```
[332, 605]-[332, 592], srednica: 13
```

your input will be

1. into `tmp` it will put `"[332,"`
2. into `ax` it will put the `605`
3. into `tmp` it will put `"]-[332,"`
4. into `ay` it will put `592`
5. into `tmp` it will put `"],"`
6. into `bx` it will *try* to read the string `"srednica"` which is not a valid number, and the input will fail and set the `fail` flag on the input stream, making **all** the following inputs invalid

---

How to replace any non-digit character in a string to a space using [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform):

```
std::string s = "[332, 605]-[332, 592]";
std::cout << "Before: \"" << s << "\"\n";

std::transform(std::begin(s), std::end(s), std::begin(s),
    [](const char& ch) -> char
    {
        return (std::isdigit(ch) ? ch : ' ');
    });

std::cout << "After : \"" << s << "\"\n";
```

The above code prints

```
Before: "[332, 605]-[332, 592]"
After : " 332  605   332  592 "
```

Comment: You are completly right! Now i realised why im getting 2 good values and 2 trashes. I cant find good example of std::transform so i replaced step by step `'[' ']' '-' ','`

Comment: @user3804906 Follow the links in my answer. :)